# Unable to load TensorFlow model after saving;

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I tried to build a simple TensorFlow model which went smoothly, it was working as intended then I saved it and now I am unable to load it back into the workflow.

My code is:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
import tensorflow as tf
# from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D,Dense,Flatten,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import Rescaling
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, BatchNormalization, Conv2D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.losses import CategoricalCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping

import os
os.mkdir("./Dataset")
os.mkdir("./Dataset/train")
os.mkdir("./Dataset/test")
os.mkdir("./Dataset/resize train")
os.mkdir("./Dataset/resize test")

import os
import numpy as np
import shutil

rootdir= 'Seg_images' #path of the original folder
sub_class = os.listdir(rootdir)
# print(sub_class)
for classes in sub_class:
    os.mkdir("./Dataset/train/"+classes)
    os.mkdir("./Dataset/test/"+classes)
    os.mkdir("./Dataset/resize train/"+classes)
    os.mkdir("./Dataset/resize test/"+classes)

#Dataset in train and test folder

import os
import numpy as np
import shutil

rootdir= 'Seg_images' #path of the original folder
sub_class = os.listdir(rootdir)

for classes in sub_class:  
    path_to_class = rootdir + '/' + classes
    allimgs = os.listdir(path_to_class)
    np.random.shuffle(allimgs)
    test_ratio = 0.25
    train_FileNames, test_FileNames = np.split(np.array(allimgs),[int(len(allimgs)* (1 - test_ratio))])
    train_FileNames = [path_to_class+'/'+ name for name in train_FileNames.tolist()]
    test_FileNames = [path_to_class+'/' + name for name in test_FileNames.tolist()]
    for name in train_FileNames:
        shutil.copy( name ,'./Dataset/train/' + classes)
    for name in test_FileNames:
        shutil.copy(name,'./Dataset/test/' + classes)
        #print(classes,'&&&&&&',name)

IMG_WIDTH = 256
IMG_HEIGHT = 256
BATCH_SIZE = 32

import os
from PIL import Image
images_path = []

src_train_path = './Dataset/train/'
dst_train_path = './Dataset/resize train/'

src_test_path = './Dataset/test/'
dst_test_path = './Dataset/resize test/'

train_dir = os.listdir(src_train_path)

test_dir = os.listdir(src_test_path)
print('//',train_dir)

lst = []

for img_list in train_dir:
    
    x = src_train_path+img_list
#     print(x)
#     print(os.listdir(x))

    img_folders = lst = os.listdir(x)
#   
    
    for img_name in img_folders:
        img_dst_train_path = dst_train_path + img_list +'/' + img_name
        img_src_train_path = src_train_path + '/' + img_list + '/' + img_name
        images_path.append(str(img_dst_train_path))
        img = Image.open(img_src_train_path)
        img = img.resize((256,256),Image.LANCZOS)
        img.save(img_dst_train_path)

for img_list in test_dir:

    x = src_test_path+img_list 
    img_folders = os.listdir(x)

    for img_name in img_folders:
        img_dst_test_path = dst_test_path + '/'+ img_list +'/' + img_name
        img_src_test_path = src_test_path + '/'+ img_list +'/' + img_name
        img = Image.open(img_src_test_path)
        img = img.resize((256,256),Image.LANCZOS)
        img.save(img_dst_test_path)
        

train_dataset_path = './Dataset/resize train/'
validation_dataset_path = './Dataset/resize test/'

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255,
                                  zoom_range=0.2,
                                  width_shift_range=0.2,
                                  height_shift_range=0.2,
                                  fill_mode='nearest')
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dataset_path,
                                                   target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
                                                   batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                   class_mode='categorical',
                                                   shuffle=True)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_dataset_path,
                                                             target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
                                                             batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                             class_mode='categorical',
                                                             shuffle=True)

def create_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        Conv2D(32, 2, activation='relu'),
        MaxPooling2D(),
      
        Conv2D(64,(3,3),2, activation='relu'),
        MaxPooling2D(),
      
        Conv2D(128, 2, activation='relu'),
        MaxPooling2D(),
      
        Conv2D(128,(3,3),2, activation='relu'),
        MaxPooling2D(),
      
        Conv2D(64,(3,3),1, activation='relu'),
    
        Flatten(),
        Dense(128, activation='relu'),  
        Dense(30, activation='softmax'),
        ]
    )
    
    return model


cnn_model.compile(
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss =[tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),],
    metrics = ["accuracy"],
    )

history = cnn_model.fit(train_generator,epochs = 100,verbose = 1,validation_data = validation_generator)

cnn_model.save("cnn-model.h5")
cnn_model.save("cnn-model.keras")
```

However, when I try to load this model, I get the error:
*The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. The input_shape received is (None, None, None, None), where axis -1 (0-based) is the channel dimension, which found to be `None`.
Selection deleted
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('cnn-model.keras')*

I searched it for quite a bit and found reddit thread with a similar problem, the solution however didn't work.